# Как передать уровень логгирования в логгер

Tags: java, логирование, slf4j

У меня есть логгер

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

.....

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemCache.class);

.....

private void printLog(String msg) {

    LOGGER.error( msg +" \n" +
            "MAX_KEY_AFTER_HASH_LENGTH ={} + \n" +
            "cacheName = {} +\n " +
            "namespace = {} \n " +
            "в сумме  = {}", MAX_KEY_AFTER_HASH_LENGTH, getName().length(), getNamespace().length(), (MAX_KEY_AFTER_HASH_LENGTH + getName().length() + getNamespace().length()));
}
```

У меня есть 2 случая, когда общая длина всех строк близка к порогу, нужно вывести **LOGGER.warn()**, когда ошибка, нужно **LOGGER.error**.
Возможно ли как-то это передать в рамках параметра? Прописывать что-то наподобии `if(isWarnOrError)` мне кажется некрасивым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slf4j не поддерживает передачу уровня логгирования как параметр, однако вы можете воспользоваться таким свитчем:

```
public class LoggingUtils {

public static void logByLevel(Logger log, Level level, String message) {
    switch (level) {
        case WARN:
            log.warn(message);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            log.error(message);
            break;
        case DEBUG:
            log.debug(message);
            break;
        case TRACE:
            log.trace(message);
            break;
        default:
            log.info(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Получается, весь msg который внутри логгера в моем вопросе, мне нужно передавать ... Ну, в любом случае спасибо) Совсем забыл про свитч

Comment: А в качестве Level какой класс вы передаете? `java.util.logging` ?

Comment: @Dred org.slf4j.event.Level из org.slf4j:slf4j-api

Comment: А, у меня библиотека старая оказалась, там нет этого класса. Спасибо